# How to limit the pan gesture to the maximum height of the image when zooming?

Tags: flutter

How to limit height image on zoom in interact viewer during zoom? If during Zoom the image occupies the entire screen, the black bars cannot appear, the pan must reach the maximum height of the image.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    interactiveController = TransformationController();
    zoomController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
    )..addListener(() {
        interactiveController.value = zoomAnimation.value;
      });
    super.initState();
  }

 void handleDoubleTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    doubleTapDetails = details;
  }

  void handleDoubleTap(ZoomCubit cubit) {
    late Matrix4 endMatrix;
    if (interactiveController.value != Matrix4.identity()) {
      endMatrix = Matrix4.identity();
    } else {
      final Offset position = doubleTapDetails!.localPosition;

      endMatrix = Matrix4.identity()
        ..translate(-position.dx, -position.dy)
        ..scale(2.0);
    }

    zoomAnimation = Matrix4Tween(
      begin: interactiveController.value,
      end: endMatrix,
    ).animate(
      CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOut).animate(zoomController),
    );
    zoomController.forward(from: 0);

    if (interactiveController.value != Matrix4.identity()) {
      cubit.shouldZoom();
    } else {
      cubit.shouldShrink();
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    final size = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context);
    final cubit = BlocProvider.of<ZoomCubit>(context);
    return GestureDetector(
      onDoubleTap: () => handleDoubleTap(cubit),
      onDoubleTapDown: handleDoubleTapDown,
      child: SizedBox.expand(
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          scaleEnabled: true,
          transformationController: interactiveController,
          onInteractionUpdate: (details) async {
              if (interactiveController.value[0] > 1.0) {
                cubit.shouldShrink();
              }else{
                cubit.shouldZoom();
              }
          },
```

If during Zoom the image occupies the entire screen, the black bars cannot appear, the pan must reach the maximum height of the image.

[video showing the zoom experience blocking the view of nearby bars](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sFNNVU0dMNCuRWcdmKdh8j7o94vl36ev/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Consider the Image child interactviewer